# angular 2 use a javascript package in typescript

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, signalr

I'm trying to use SignalR in an Ionic/Angular 2 application.

I'm building a simple Hub like so:

```
const accessToken = authManager.getRawAccessToken();

let hubUrl = environment.baseUrl + 'messages';
if (accessToken) {
    hubUrl += '?authToken=' + accessToken;
}

this._hubConnection = new HubConnectionBuilder()
                           .withUrl(hubUrl)
                           .build();
```

I keep getting an error:

> Cannot find name 'XMLHttpRequestResponseType'.

because SignalR requires a higher version of typescript than what's support currently by Ionic.  https://github.com/aspnet/SignalR/issues/1375

I noticed SignalR is shipped by default using Javascript.  Is there a way I can change my Import statement

```
import { HubConnection, HubConnectionBuilder } from '@aspnet/signalr';
```

So I can import javascript into a Typescript file as Any?

**Edit**
I've also tried:

```
import * as SignalR from '@aspnet/signalr';
```

but this still seems to use the typings file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> To use Js instead of Typescript?

Use raw `require`:

```
const { HubConnection, HubConnectionBuilder } =  require('@aspnet/signalr');
```

The types for `require` are provided by `npm i @types/node`

Comment: @basaray, To clarify, I want to import a raw js into a type script file, I'm getting an error cannot find name require

Comment: `npm install @types/node` 

Comment: I also needed `declare var require: any`